# Show saved date in label

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I´m saving a date in a table like this:

```
Me!lastchangedate.Caption = Now

  Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("background", dbOpenTable)
        rs.AddNew
        rs![date] = Me!lastchangedate.Caption
        rs.Update
        rs.Close
```

Later I want to read this date out of the database and show it in a Label:

```
sqlstrdate = "SELECT date FROM background " _
    & " WHERE SAP_ID = '" _
    & Me!sapidtxt.Value & "'"

retvaldate = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlstrdate)
```

Until here it´s working but if I now try to show "retvaldate" as MsgBox or in a label I always get the error message: Error 13 type mismatch.

Im trying to use this to show the saved date in a label.

```
Me!lastchangedate.Caption = (retvaldate)
```

Is there an option to change the label type or do I have to change the "retvaldate" to a date type (which also gives me the same error).

Comment: It´s saying "Recordset2". What does this mean?

Comment: But the date is correctly saved in my table, how can I read it out there and show it in a label?

Comment: Do you have another solution for reading a date from table and show it in a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set 'retvaldate' like opening a recordset. The following should provide the correct result (BTW, why do you use reserved words like 'date' as a field name?)

```
Dim rs          As Recordset
Dim sqlstrdate  As String

sqlstrdate = "SELECT date FROM background " _
    & " WHERE SAP_ID = '" _
    & Me!sapidtxt.Value & "'"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlstrdate)
If Not rs.EOF Then
    retvaldate = rs.Fields("Date")
Else
    retvaldate = "No Records"
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

'Then later... but I hope the variable is in scope (Global, form, subroutine)
Me!lastchangedate.Caption = retvaldate
```

Comment: It´s working, thank you! 'date' is no field name, I changed it for a better understanding, im my program the fields name is a bit confusing.